# Replace 'nan' by blank while uploading data from python to postgresql using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a dataframe where I do have some null values. Except ID and date cols, all are `string`.

```
ID    product_num    order_date   desc      employeID
1     100234         2020-02-03   abcx       101
2                                            102
```

Problem is when I try to upload the above dataframe to postgresql (v 11) then the blank cells are converted to string `nan`. So in DB I see the following

```
 ID    product_num    order_date   desc      employeID
  1     100234         2020-02-03   abcx       101
  2        nan          nan          nan       102
```

Clearly this is not expected. Instead I would like to see them as blank (or NULL) in the DB as well.

How to work around this issue? I am converting all the columns in df to psycopg2 equivalent datatype as per below function:

```
def sqlcol(df):    
  dtypedict = {}
  for i,j in zip(dfcolumns, dfdtypes):
    if "object" in str(j):
        dtypedict.update({i: sqlalchemy.types.String()})
    if "datetime" in str(j):
        dtypedict.update({i: sqlalchemy.types.DateTime()})
    if "float" in str(j):
        dtypedict.update({i: sqlalchemy.types.String()})
    if "int" in str(j):
        dtypedict.update({i: sqlalchemy.types.String()})
  return dtypedict
```

But I am not getting any result.
Thus any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you uploading the dataframe to Postgres(the exact command)? When you say the columns(except ID and date) are string are you talking about the Postgres columns? Are the blanks in the data frame actually `NULL` or are they empty strings?

Comment: I am using df.to_sql() and there I am using the above `sqlcol(df)` function to change the datatype. In the dataframe it is coming as `nan` and they are actually blank.